# Can't find folders in Exchange (EWS) : "Mailbox does not exist"

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS with java to retrieve emails from an Outlook mailbox.

I can fetch emails from Inbox with no problem :

```
  FolderId inbox=new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(account));

  return service.findItems(inbox, new ItemView(15))
        .getItems()
        .stream()
        .map(item -> toEmail(item))
        .collect(toList());
```

I now need to look into specific folders, and all the examples I could find look something like this :

```
private FolderId findSpecificFolder(ExchangeService service, String folderName) throws Exception {

    FolderView view = new FolderView(10);
    PropertySet prop= new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    prop.add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);

    view.setPropertySet(prop);
    view.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);

    FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);

    ...
}
```

But the call to `service.findFolders` yields an exception :

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: Mailbox does not exist.

at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.internalThrowIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:278)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.response.ServiceResponse.throwIfNecessary(ServiceResponse.java:267)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:165)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalFindFolders(ExchangeService.java:377)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findFolders(ExchangeService.java:425)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.findFolders(ExchangeService.java:461)
```

I am confused because it works nicely when I just get the inbox content.. So the mailbox does exist !

Is there an alternative that works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround - but not sure why the initial code is not working.

Going though `Folder.bind` did the trick for me, and this works :

```
private FolderId findSpecificFolder(ExchangeService service, String folderName) throws Exception {

    //reusing the Inbox FolderId that was working
    FolderId inbox=new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(account));

    FolderView view = new FolderView(10);
    PropertySet prop= new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    prop.add(FolderSchema.DisplayName);

    view.setPropertySet(prop);
    view.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);

    //Binding the inboxFolder
    Folder inboxFolder=Folder.bind(service, inbox);

    FindFoldersResults subFolders=inboxFolder.findFolders(view);

    for (Folder subFolder : subFolders.getFolders()){
       ...
    } 
}
```